# When I tried to install sacrebleu, I got an installation error

Tags: python

**Description**

When I tried to install package `sacrebleu`, I got an error like this:
[Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC2Rf.png)

It said "System cannot find the specified file". However I have no idea how to solve it.

I have tried installing package `mecab-python3`. But it confuses me that it was successfully installed in Anaconda but got an error, "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required", in original python38 environment.

Whether the package `mecab-python3` has been installed or not, I still got the same error and cannot install `sacrebleu`.

I also tried restarting my machine but it does not work.

Is there anyone could solve it? or I want to know if there is any alternative package I can use to calculate BLEU score.

Thanks Anyway!

**My Environment**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8
- pip 20.1.1
- Anaconda3 v4.8.2

Comment: Lol sacrebleu, du travail de pirate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the mecab-python3 maintainer. Sorry it's giving you trouble.

The [README](https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3#common-issues) has a link to the C++ runtime pack you have to install on Windows, if you install that it should work.

I have heard reports of the package not working with Anaconda on Windows specifically, though it seems to work sometimes. If you have trouble please open an issue and I'll try to fix it. On the other hand, if you aren't processing Japanese there's no reason to import the module and that may be a bug in sacrebleu.

---

Ah, actually, I just saw your screenshot - didn't notice it before.

Versions before 1.0 don't support Windows. But to keep using the old dictionary, sacrebleu has to make some changes, so they don't support 1.0+ yet. I think they are working on it, see [this issue](https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu/issues/94).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!! Really helps me a lot!!

Comment: This should be resolved in the latest sacrebleu release.